# drag and drop isn't functioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a beginner at Javascript and I'm trying to get the image to go inside the border that is made with css and for some reason the script isn't functioning it might be that i had a small mistake in the code or something else.

The snippet works fine but it doesn't show the image.

"e" is short for event
i have a:
drag(e)
allowdrop(e)
and drop(e)

Thanks

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>drag and drop</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    #targetDiv {
      margin-left: 300px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 150px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #999999;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>drag and drop</h1>

  <div id="targetDiv" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)"></div>
  <img id="dragItem" src="market-street-car.jpg" width="200" height="150" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />

  <script>
    function drag(e) {
      e.dataTransfer.setData("Text", e.target.id);
    }

    function allowDrop(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    function drop(e) {
      var dragItem = e.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
      e.preventDefault();
      e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(dragItem));
    }
//You don't need to edit this one cuz you don't need var var is probably optional 

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `dataTransfer` is set to `Text` ?

Comment: dataTransfer is named text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is corrected version.
You have missed an `)` character, and I've added one `var` expression exactly here: take.ms/el76e

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>drag and drop</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    #targetDiv {
      margin-left: 300px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 150px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #999999;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>drag and drop</h1>

  <div id="targetDiv" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)"></div>
  <img id="dragItem" src="market-street-car.jpg" width="200" height="150" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />

  <script>
    function drag(e) {
      e.dataTransfer.setData("Text", e.target.id);
    }

    function allowDrop(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    function drop(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var dragItem = e.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
      e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(dragItem));
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As I said missing ) character, I've updated Your topic to make it more clear

Comment: thanks but you could've mentioned where earlier and you don't need var

Comment: I've updated my answer with picture to show "where" for others. Good luck with further work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code isn't working with the image, since all I can get from running the code snippet is the result of the "allowDrop" function. An error like the one on your dragItem could cause this:

```
ragstart="drag(event"
```

Is missing the closing ")"

One thing I always do when debugging Javascript is open the Js console (ctrl+shift+j) and monitor it as I go through the page, an error could appear briefly that you wouldn't otherwise find just running the page itself.